# No wifi 19.04 kernel 5.0.0-23

Tags: networking, kernel

Further to my problem [No WiFi after upgrade (Realtek RTL8188CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163588/no-wifi-after-upgrade):

- I ran wireless-info, as instructed, found on this recommended page: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and pasted the results here:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kFTK62fmqB/
- No network devices available on 19.04 if I use kernel 5.0.0-23
- Wireless works fine on 19.04 if I use kernel 5.0.0-21
- Wireless works fine on Windows 10 (dual boot)
- Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)

Thank you Pilot6 very much, but my adapter is RTL8188CE, and the download referred to in your link is another model, not supported on >18.10.  I can't understand why I get wifi using kernel 5.0.0-21 yet not on 5.0.0-23?

Thank you to everyone.  In case it helps, I have pasted the result of wireless-info script from 19.04 when I am using kernel 5.0.0-21 (on which I do have wifi): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zDx74FtSHn/  I don't know whether the comparison with the script result on kernel 5.0.0-23 (without wifi) would help?  My problems did actually start with the update I ran a week after I had upgraded from 18.10 (wifi worked fine until then), so is it possible it could be broken packages?  Once again apologies, I am away from my own computer until weekend. Thanks again!

Comment: This question likely has nothing to do with wifi but instead the broken package manager state.

Comment: **Voting to reopen:** The current closure looks incorrect. The target question is about RTL8821CE but OP is using RTL8188CE. **@KristopherIves:** They are two different and independent issues, I think. **antunny:** Please redact the other  parts such as security risks, broken packages, etc. If it is unsolved, consider posting a separate question since here one question is expected to focus on one issue.